# Use Monaco editor in web application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, powershell, monaco-editor

We have an MVC web application in which Powershell is used as scripting engine. Currently a textarea element is used for script editing which turns out to be very cumbersome. As Microsoft released [Monaco Editor](https://github.com/Microsoft/monaco-editor), we were wondering if we could embed the editor in our application as a widget to leverage its capability of syntax check and intellisense. After checking out their documentation, not much related info could be found. Is this possible or Microsoft is not currently supporting the use in a third-party application?

Comment: Yes you can...actually they do it in their demo page: https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/

Comment: @Hackerman, yes, I also saw the demo, but it looks more like a demo of how you could use monaco editor in _MS services_ such as Azure rather than using the editor as a widget within your _own application_.

Comment: Not at all...you can use it in your own app,you just need to include the relevant js and css files, and that's it

Comment: @Hackerman, thank you for your prompt response, however, I could not find what are and where to retrieve related js and css files. Could you point me to them?

Comment: I am going to build an jsfiddle, with all the code and files, just wait like...half hour?

Comment: @Hackerman that would be extremely helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Almost there :) https://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/r1b9hbhk/3/

Comment: I did it https://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/r1b9hbhk/5/

Comment: If you want I can post an answer with all the steps :)

Comment: It works like a charm! @Hackerman thank you so much. I wonder how you could piece together all the necessary js and css that scatter around. I think it's a good idea that you post an answer so others could be helped.

Comment: I just have to study the code...make some replacements to point out to the right namespaces and look at the network tab...I am going to put a full answer

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a workaround to include the `Monarc Editor`on your website, it still requires files from Microsoft to works, but, it should be work if we download those files locally and modify the `baseUrl` to point to the right folder:

> Basic HTML Code

```
<section class="try">
    <div class="container">
    <h3>Editor</h3>
        <div class="editor row">
            <div class="span3">                 
                <p>Colorizers are implemented using <a href="monarch.html"
                    target="_blank">Monarch</a>.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="span9">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="span4">
                        <label class="control-label">Language</label>
                        <select class="language-picker"></select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="span4">
                        <label class="control-label">Theme</label>
                        <select class="theme-picker">
                            <option>Visual Studio</option>
                            <option>Visual Studio Dark</option>
                            <option>High Contrast Dark</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="editor-frame">
                    <div class="loading editor" style="display: none;">
                        <div class="progress progress-striped active">
                            <div class="bar"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="editor"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>   
   </div>
</section>
```

> JavaScript Code:

```
'use strict';
require.config({
    baseUrl: 'https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/node_modules/monaco-editor/min/'
});


var editor = null,
    diffEditor = null;

$(document).ready(function() {
    require(['vs/editor/editor.main'], function() {
        var MODES = (function() {
            var modesIds = monaco.languages.getLanguages().map(function(lang) {
                return lang.id;
            });
            modesIds.sort();

            return modesIds.map(function(modeId) {
                return {
                    modeId: modeId,
                    sampleURL: 'https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/index/samples/sample.' + modeId + '.txt'
                };
            });
        })();

        for (var i = 0; i < MODES.length; i++) {
            var o = document.createElement('option');
            o.textContent = MODES[i].modeId;
            $(".language-picker").append(o);
        }
        $(".language-picker").change(function() {
            loadSample(MODES[this.selectedIndex]);
        });
        $('.language-picker').selectpicker({
            size: 10
        });
        loadSample(MODES[0]);

        $(".theme-picker").change(function() {
            changeTheme(this.selectedIndex);
        });
        $('.theme-picker').selectpicker({
            size: 3
        });

        loadDiffSample();

        $('#inline-diff-checkbox').change(function() {
            diffEditor.updateOptions({
                renderSideBySide: !$(this).is(':checked')
            });
        });
    });

    window.onresize = function() {
        if (editor) {
            editor.layout();
        }
        if (diffEditor) {
            diffEditor.layout();
        }
    };
});

function loadSample(mode) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: mode.sampleURL,
        dataType: 'text',
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('.loading.editor').show();
        },
        error: function() {
            if (editor) {
                if (editor.getModel()) {
                    editor.getModel().dispose();
                }
                editor.dispose();
                editor = null;
            }
            $('.loading.editor').fadeOut({
                duration: 200
            });
            $('#editor').empty();
            $('#editor').append('<p class="alert alert-error">Failed to load ' + mode.modeId + ' sample</p>');
        }
    }).done(function(data) {
        if (!editor) {
            $('#editor').empty();
            editor = monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById('editor'), {
                model: null,
            });
        }

        var oldModel = editor.getModel();
        var newModel = monaco.editor.createModel(data, mode.modeId);
        editor.setModel(newModel);
        if (oldModel) {
            oldModel.dispose();
        }
        $('.loading.editor').fadeOut({
            duration: 300
        });
    });
}

function loadDiffSample() {

    var onError = function() {
        $('.loading.diff-editor').fadeOut({
            duration: 200
        });
        $('#diff-editor').append('<p class="alert alert-error">Failed to load diff editor sample</p>');
    };

    $('.loading.diff-editor').show();

    var lhsData = null,
        rhsData = null,
        jsMode = null;

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/index/samples/diff.lhs.txt',
        dataType: 'text',
        error: onError
    }).done(function(data) {
        lhsData = data;
        onProgress();
    });

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/index/samples/diff.rhs.txt',
        dataType: 'text',
        error: onError
    }).done(function(data) {
        rhsData = data;
        onProgress();
    });

    function onProgress() {
        if (lhsData && rhsData) {
            diffEditor = monaco.editor.createDiffEditor(document.getElementById('diff-editor'), {
                enableSplitViewResizing: false
            });

            var lhsModel = monaco.editor.createModel(lhsData, 'text/javascript');
            var rhsModel = monaco.editor.createModel(rhsData, 'text/javascript');

            diffEditor.setModel({
                original: lhsModel,
                modified: rhsModel
            });

            $('.loading.diff-editor').fadeOut({
                duration: 300
            });
        }
    }
}

function changeTheme(theme) {
    var newTheme = (theme === 1 ? 'vs-dark' : (theme === 0 ? 'vs' : 'hc-black'));
    if (editor) {
        editor.updateOptions({
            'theme': newTheme
        });
    }
    if (diffEditor) {
        diffEditor.updateOptions({
            'theme': newTheme
        });
    }
}
```

#### Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/r1b9hbhk/

Comment: do you know any reason why when I tried this workaround in a clean MVC application it could work, but when it was used in my real project, an error of `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined` appeared. Moreover, I noticed if you replaced the source of jquery reference in jsfiddle to [link](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js) it would generate errors. And that's a difference between my project(jquery 2.2.1) and a clean MVC application(jquery 1.9.1).

Comment: If you check the Monaco Editor demo, they use Jquery 1.9.1, so it is possible that the Editor doesn't works with a higher version....

Comment: @Hackerman intellsense is not working in that demo I beleive the person did request it

Comment: @rogue39nin This demo is 4 years old...also the OP accepted the answer 